# Video Conferencing in ASP.NET, flash, silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, flash

I need to implement video conferencing in a ASP.Net application.

We have cases that contains 3 users. Per case we need to set up a Video Conferencing possibility.

Are there any services or libraries to use for this functionality?

EDIT:

TokBox was a good service to use, however I need a solution to maintain on own servers now. Are there existing services that let me do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: http://www.red5chat.com/.

By far your easiest solution at this point will be to embed Flash into your ASP.NET pages. You can use Red5 as your media server backend if you want a free and pretty good solution. (You can also pay for back-end media server solutions like Wowza or Flash Media Server.)

You can in theory do this with Silverlight (see http://silverlightvideochat.codeplex.com/), but it's not nearly as sophisticated as the Flash solutions, i.e., the video codec isn't nearly as good, there's no AEC, noise reduction, etc.

As for HTML5, Google has open-sourced WebRTC, and it's working its way through the standards process. But it's currently supported by ~0% of the browsers out there. (It was released into the Chrome dev channel in mid January: http://www.webrtc.org/blog/webrtcnowavailableinthechromedevchannel.)

But the short answer, again, is "Use Flash on the client and Red5 on the server."

EDIT: With a little bit more client-side coding and Adobe's RTMFP solution, you can create a peer-to-peer Flash-based solution that doesn't use a server. It won't scale to more than 2-4 users per "room", but it'll have very low latency, and won't require you to standup and support a server. See [here](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/) to get started.

Also, the production channel of Google's Chrome now supports WebRTC (and so does Opera). You can see a demo of it [here](https://apprtc.appspot.com/?r=82924098). Firefox also supports a version of it, but the two aren't yet compatible, though achieving interoperability is a high priority for both dev teams. Neither IE nor Safari has yet announced support.

[Tokbox](http://www.tokbox.com/) also has a reasonably simple API that will allow you to use WebRTC when it's available (it produces higher quality audio/video than Flash), and degrade to Flash when it's not. It's free for 1:1 sessions or for less than 25,000 group minutes per month.